# SQL, how to select all following records after a certain value; by user_id

Tags: sql

I have a table looks like this:

```
user_id | event_id | action
--------+----------+--------
user_1  | 1        | view 
user_1  | 2        | enter
user_1  | 3        | sign_up
user_1  | 4        | view
user_2  | 1        | view
user_2  | 2        | sign_up
user_2  | 3        | enter
user_2  | 4        | view
```

So the `event_id` is associated with a user, following an order when the event happened.

What I was trying to achieve here: I want to look at after users did the 'sign_up' event what else would they do.

I need to select all the rows after `action` = 'sign_up' by different `user_id`.

The query I was testing and had problems:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE event_id >= (
  SELECT event_id
  FROM table
  WHERE action = 'sign_up'
  ORDER BY event_id ASC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

This will simply take out `event_id` = 1 and apply to all users.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep it simple and just use a join approach:

```
SELECT t1.USER_ID, t1.EVENT_ID, t1.ACTION
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT USER_ID, EVENT_ID
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE ACTION = 'sign_up'
) t2
    ON t1.USER_ID = t2.USER_ID AND
       t1.EVENT_ID > t2.EVENT_ID
ORDER BY t1.USER_ID, t1.EVENT_ID;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

The idea here is to join to a subquery which finds, for each user, the exact `EVENT_ID` numerical value on which the signup event occurred.  Then, we restrict to rows in your original table on the condition that the event happened after the signup.  Note that for users which never had a signup, none of their records would appear in the result set.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried yours and it worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

You need a co-related subquery so that the sub-query is evaluated for each user_id separately:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM the_table t1
WHERE event_id >= (SELECT event_id 
                   from the_table t2
                   where t2.action = 'sign_up' 
                     and t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                   ORDER BY EVENT_ID ASC
                   limit 1 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe to do with the tool I'm using, it gave me error: 'Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated' (fyi.I'm using Tableau's custom SQL)